# Screen Sharing won't allow me to paste into remote system

Tags: screen-sharing, copy-paste

I am connected to a remote system via Screen Sharing.  I have text (plaintext) on my clipboard locally.  I am unable to paste into the remote system.  How can I make this work?  Here are some details:

- When I open the Edit menu, only "Copy" is available, "Paste", "Send Clipboard" and "Get Clipboard" and so on are grayed out.
- The buttons for "Send Clipboard" and "Get Clipboard" are grayed out.

  [image]

Some other facts:

- The clipboard functions work ok with JollyFastVNC and Chicken of the VNC (but I have other problems with these).
- Both local and remote systems are on OSX 10.6.8
- Keyboard and mouse functionality works fine to remote system
- The remote system's local clipboard works fine -- if I CTL-V in a screen on the remote system, I paste what is on the remote system's clipboard (hope that makes sense)
- It doesn't matter what app I'm in on the remote system

Comment: Are you sure your clipboard is not empty? Send Clipboard being grayed out would indicate it is.

Comment: Yep, I am sure.  I can copy and paste in my local apps just fine.  If I copy something from TextWrangler locally, then go to Screen Sharing, I see what I've screenshot above.

Comment: Have you tried copying from Safari or another native OSX app? Maybe TextWrangler isn't really using the system keyboard?

Comment: great suggestion, but yes, I have, from Outlook, Safari, Chrome... wherever...

Comment: What result do you get from doing it the other way around? so copy from teh shared screen to yours.

Comment: I would recommend checking the 'Sharing' preferences on that machine to make sure everything is allowed and there is no conflict with ARD (Remote Management) settings. You might want to just trying turning those two sharing features off then rebooting even.

Comment: I had been hoping that  MacOS mojave would fix this but nope, it seems it is one of the many areas they have not touched....

Answer (score 8):

Apple answer: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH14152

> Choose Edit >Use Shared Clipboard.
>   Using the shared clipboard, you can:
>
> Copy text and images from documents on one Mac and paste them into documents on the other.
>
> Select and drag text and images from one Mac to the other.
>
> Copy a link from your web browser and paste it into a web browser on the other Mac.
>
> Copy text from a document on one Mac and drop it on the desktop of the other Mac to create a clipping.

Comment: What if `Use Shared Clipboard` is disabled?

Comment: Link rot in effect. source is 404, and context missing so this does not work (Edit > Use Shared Clipboard is *not* present)  on  Mojave (10.14) Mac,

Answer (score 4):

I just disconnected my screen sharing session and re-connected and the copy/paste started working again.

Comment: this worked for me until the next time I needed to copy/paste, at which point I had to disconnect and re-connect a second time.

Answer (score 1):

You can drag and drop what you want to copy over.
This works on Lion, and I'd imagine it would work on earlier versions of OS X.

Comment: drag and drop text from my local app to a remote system?  or drag and drop files from local finder to remote finder?  either way, neither works.

Comment: I can't find the documentation to back up that it was NOT available in Snow Leopard (10.6) but this was hailed as a new feature by many blogs when either Lion or Mountain Lion launched.

Answer (score -1):

You could alternatively use the inbuilt VNC viewer to screen share, it has a "Get Remote Clipboard" and "Put to Remote Clipboard" feature that would overcome the issue you're having.

[Instructions](http://www.wikihow.com/Setup-VNC-on-Mac-OS-X)

Answer (score -1):

On my mac, the copy function is resource dependent. If I have too many items open consuming too much OS/RAM/etc then copy paste will not work. It recovers when I close some things.